# How to get HTTP response from website in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to see if I enter URL + ' I will get a response, but I get an error: "403 forbidden"

here is my code:

```
foreach(string s in urls)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(s + "'");
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (request.GetResponse() == null)
        {
            Valid.Add(s);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL are you hitting? `403` usually means you have to login or have some sort of authentication. If urls is secured with protocols like `https`, you may have to pass credentials and/or certificate along with request.

Comment: If you get an error, I guess that means you can't hit that URL with a `'`...?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Credentials before making the call.
The credentials should be prepared according to the web server authentication method.

1) if it is windows authentication, you can get the windows context credential by

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
//if you know the user/pass, and domain
new NetworkCredential(sCredentialUserName, sCredentialPassword, sDomain);
```

this is usually the case in a enterprise domain environment.

2) if it is basic authentication and you know the user/pass, you can use same way to create the credential without domain.

```
new NetworkCredential(sCredentialUserName, sCredentialPassword);
```

About request and response, usually I prefer to use System.Net.WebClient and also create a wrapper class for it according to the requirements.

when you make the call, it would be something like this:

```
using (System.Net.WebClient cli = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
  ......
    //set credentials
    cli.Credentials = Credentials;
    //set headers
    cli.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    //make a sync call
    response = cli.UploadString(sRemoteUrl, "POST", sJsonRequest);
    ......
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are calling `request.GetResponse()` twice, why? Also you can get the 403 forbidden if there are some credentials needed or you are missing header. You may try to add to `WebRequest` the `Method`, `ContentType` (xml, json), `Credentials` (if there are any).,

Comment: oh, I just want to see if the URL work if I add ' after the URL or if there is any error

Comment: is it possible to check if the URL return any error if I add ' without any Credentials?

Comment: You can try using Postman to see if the URL you are using is actually correct and you receive any response, also I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with adding ' at the end of the URL. I think that this is mistake

Comment: Postman is a tool you can use to call services and you see what is the response, this is fast way to check your URL what is returning

Comment: oh, but the whole point is to try to make my own tool, not others

Comment: Yes, I know, this is only to help you test if the Url is correct and what headers you need. Then you can construct it with c#